# Video card won't work with motherboard

Tags: video, graphics-card, motherboard, bios

I'm having trouble installing a video card in my computer (specs. detailed below).
Without the video card, everything works fine. I can boot into the OS without a problem, and I can even get into the BIOS setup screen.

But with the video card installed - and the HDMI cable plugged into it instead of the motherboard - I get the following:

- I turn on the machine, and it stays on this screen:
  [image: Start-up screen]
- I can't get into the BIOS (keystrokes seem to do nothing), and the machine won't boot.
- After 10 to  15 seconds, I get a short beep.
- After ~25 seconds, I get another short beep.
- After 25 - 30 seconds, I get another short beep and the computer goes to this screen:
  [image: Video card screen]

Here are the video settings in the BIOS:
[image: BIOS video settings]

Hardware:

- CPU - Intel Core i5-2400
- Operating System - Windows 7
- Case - Fractal Design Node 202
- PSU - Fractal Integra SFX 450W (came with the case)
- Motherboard - Intel <del>DQ67EP</del> DH77DF m-ITX
- CPU Cooler - Cryorig C7 CR-C7A
- Memory - Crucial 8GB Kit (4GB x 2) DDR3L
- Storage - PNY CS1311 120GB 2.5" SATA III SSD
- WiFi Adapter - ANEWKODI 600Mbps Dual Band (2.4G/150Mbps+5G/433Mbps) Wireless USB Wifi Adapter

I know the computer works without this video card; I've also had it working before with a different video card (Nvidia GeForce GTX 580).
I also know that this video card has worked before in a different computer.

Do I need to change the video settings in the BIOS to get this working? Should I update my BIOS?

Comment: Maybe you don't need to but please try changing the primary video adapter to the discrete card instead of auto and/or disable the integrated graphics. Then [edit] and update you question with the results.,

Comment: I personally would disable the Integrated Graphics Device (Set first option to 'Disabled'). That way, the bios is not making the choice. You are.

Comment: @Chris
Tried that, but the results are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was caused due to an old version of the BIOS (0069). When I installed the latest version of the BIOS (0111), everything worked fine).

I didn't think I had an old version of the BIOS, but I was wrong due to a mix-up between motherboards; I thought the problem was with a DQ67EP when it was really with a DH77DF.